# mysql DISTINCT and Rails uniq to find unique records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a reports table in my DB. I am executing a complex query and I want to count unique report id's from the result.

I can do that using the 2 ways:

1. I use `DISTINCT` in mysql query like `select count(DISTINCT id) from reports where ...`
2. I make use of Rails uniq method on the result of executing raw sql query.

But both these numbers differ.

Also, when I use `LIMIT(n) with DISTINCT query (#1)`, both these counts match. I am not sure why this is happening! There are no NULL values for this column in my table.

This is the mysql query:

```
select count(distinct report_id)
  from table1 cas
 where not exists (select 1
                     from table2 t
                    where t.report_id = cas.report_id
                      and t.point_id = cas.point_id);
```

Rails query :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select report_id
  from table1 cas
 where not exists (select 1
                     from table2 t
                    where t.report_id = cas.report_id
                      and t.point_id = cas.point_id);").to_a.flatten.uniq.count
```

Comment: `I make use of Rails uniq method on the result of executing raw sql query.` Does your raw query contain only `id` or other columns?

Comment: could you elabobate the question with example sqls?

Comment: Added mysql query.

Comment: @and resulted without count (you can get is from relation with `to_sql`) method

Comment: can you post your raw sql query, you used in rails. The complete call

Comment: @coderVishal : Added Rails query as well

Comment: The two queries seem equivalent to me. Perhaps you're querying tables that quickly grow and thus timing is what makes the counts differ...?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already used raw sql, you might as well, use it to complete the entire task

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count (distinct report_id) 
  from table1 cas
 where not exists (select 1
                     from table2 t
                    where t.report_id = cas.report_id
                      and t.point_id = cas.point_id);").first.count
```